# HTML ссылка на файл в локальной сети

Tags: firefox, файлы, html, ссылки, браузер

Добрый день!

Есть сеть и работающая через браузер корпоративная CRM. В сети есть несколько серверов - файлохранилищ. Вопрос в том, чтобы в CRM сделать ссылки на файлы, которые расположены на этих серверах. Т.е. чтобы при нажатии на ссылку открывался (а не скачивался), например, вордовский файл, лежащий где-то в сети.

Насколько я изучил вопрос, существует формат:

```
<a href="file://10.0.0.1/path/file.docx">Ссылка на локальный файл</a>
```

Однако как я ни пытался заставить это работать, у меня не получилось. Перерыл множество форумов в поисках решения, однако все найденные решения относятся к 2012 и более ранним годам, и сейчас не срабатывают. И, насколько я понял, это во многом зависит от браузера. Меня интересует реализация для Firefox.

Интересуют любые варианты решения!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если мы говорим о "ворде", например, то в настройках браузера ставим "открывать" а не "скачивать" файлы нужных форматов и всё. Это чисто клиентская фишка.

Если же мы говорим например о тектовых файлах (которые можно смотреть прямо через браузер) - копать в сторону настроек сервера на котором лежат файлы, но в самбе я не силён, не знаю можно ли там настраивать как в апаче (например) ...

Answer (score 1):

Формально, это невозможно. Браузер не даст открыть так локальную ссылку.

Что касается FF - читал, что там был баг, что если слешей больше поставить, то он позволит. Не знаю точно.

Вообще, раз речь идёт о корпоративной сети, я так понимаю, возможно на компьютерах установить программу и зарегистрировать под неё некий протокол. После этого указывать его вместо `file://`.

Назначать протокол непосредственно Word'у небезопасно.