# Ссылка (href) на файл в локальной сети

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Стоит необходимость сделать ссылку на скачивания файла не самого сервера, а из локальной сети в которой находиться сервер:

```
<a href="//192.168.88.220/Files/РУ_2_кл_Работы.zip">РУ_2_кл_Работы</a>
```

Был несколько удивлен тому, что это не так то и просто [сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/410840/html-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8).

Есть ли способ этого достичь?

Также перепробовал различные варианты использования `file:///` `file:\\\`. Не помогает.

Comment: Эээ, а хост `192.168.88.220` доступен клиентам сервера? Если да, `file:///` должно по идее работать (хотя я не пробовал).

Comment: @VladD сделал: `<a href="file:///\\192.168.88.220\файлы_пто\Работы\[2016-15] - ДР в 1-3 классов\2 класс\РУ_2 кл_Памятка учителю.docx">РУ_2_кл_Памятка учителю</a>`. Не работает.

Comment: А ради интереса если путь весь из латиницы? И что именно значит «не работает»?

Comment: @VladD, здесь работает... security limitations. Нельзя обращаться с `http:` на `file:`.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ах вот оно что! Даже во внешних ссылках типа `a href=`?

Comment: @VladD, даже в них :( Хотя, где-то вроде как-то работало.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте отдельный метод контроллера и там что-то подобное:

```
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"//192.168.88.220/Files/РУ_2_кл_Работы.zip");
    string fileName = "some_english_name.zip";
    return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
}
```

т.е. запрос уйдёт на сервер, сервер обратится к сетевому ресурсу и отдаст файл

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
<a href="\\192.168.88.220\Files\РУ_2_кл_Работы.zip">РУ_2_кл_Работы</a>
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?